# Reduce the boilerplate of dispose() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Flutter we need to write down `dispose()` for many things we have created in a `State`, e.g.

```
  final _nameController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _nameController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Thus, I wonder whether there is a way to eliminate this need, and call the dispose automatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find another solution: [flutter_hooks](https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks)

- Pros: Almost no boilerplate!
- Cons: Need to extend from a different base class (HookWidget, not StatefulWidget)

One sample:

Before -

```
class Example extends StatefulWidget {
  final Duration duration;

  const Example({Key key, @required this.duration})
      : assert(duration != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _ExampleState createState() => _ExampleState();
}

class _ExampleState extends State<Example> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: widget.duration);
  }

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(Example oldWidget) {
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
    if (widget.duration != oldWidget.duration) {
      _controller.duration = widget.duration;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

After -

```
class Example extends HookWidget {
  final Duration duration;

  const Example({Key key, @required this.duration})
      : assert(duration != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = useAnimationController(duration: duration);
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Comment: I remember hearing about Flutter hooks but never used it--good to know! Looks like it is super useful. My guess is that it has an implementation similar to mine of dispose under the hood in the HookWidget class.

Comment: @GregoryConrad imho maybe a little bit different, actually the lib has some explanations :) https://github.com/rrousselGit/flutter_hooks#principle

Comment: I took a quick look at the source code. Instead of the disposal happening in the `dispose` method of a state class, it looks like it happens in the `unmount` of the element using the same principle that I gave above (but using the list of hooks).

Comment: @GregoryConrad sounds like that!

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options here:

1. If overriding the `dispose` method is OK in every `State` where you need to dispose some objects, simply create a list of all the objects you need to dispose and call `dispose` on them all at once. Something like this should work:

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    [objectToDispose1, objectToDispose2, objectToDispose3].forEach((o) => o.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }
```

2. If you simply do not want to override the dispose method, then you will need to go back to the basics of OOP. Reflection would be very convenient here but Flutter disallows it for performance reasons. Thus, you can make your own abstract base class that extends `State`, perhaps called `DisposableState`. This abstract class would have an abstract getter for the objects to dispose as a `List`. Then, it would reference that getter in its dispose method, using the above method from option 1:

```
  List get disposables;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    disposables.forEach((o) => o.dispose());
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Note: you can extend both of these options with objects that have `close()` instead of `dispose()`, with some slight modification that adds more boilerplate :(

Unfortunately, I believe this is the shortest way to go about mass-disposing objects as they have to be "registered" for disposal/closing somewhere, and afaik, the Flutter framework does not provide any way to do this in the basic [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) class.

Comment: Thanks! I also find another solution, see my answer below